# RestSharp: Adding content-type

Tags: http-headers, restsharp

In a previous version of RestSharp I was able to add a **content-type:application/json**

```
        RestClientOptions options = new RestClientOptions();
        options.BaseUrl = new Uri($"https://{_options.Auth0Domain}");
        var client = new RestClient(options);

        var request = new RestRequest("/oauth/token") { Method = Method.Post };
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        var response = await client.ExecuteAsync<Auth0MachineToMachineResponse>(request);
```

But after the big 107 release I get this error when I try to add the content-type, which is required by the end point I am calling:

**"Misused header name, 'content-type'. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
request.AddParameter("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", ParameterType.HttpHeader);
```

It seems is case sensitive now?

Comment: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type is used by default when making post request with regular parameters. There's a _very_ limited number of cases when you need to set the content type header manually with RestSharp.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not add content type manually.

Use `AddStringBody` and the content type for the body parameter instead.

```
var request = new RestRequest("/oauth/token").AddStringBody(json, "application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync<Auth0MachineToMachineResponse>(request);
```